# A module for generating PDFs

Tags: 7, files

I have tried PDF using mPDF and Printer-friendly pages (Drupal 7.x). They both need own styling of an output. I have got a CSS that formats my pages for printing. I would like to generate PDFs by just "printing" to them. I do not want to maintain separate styles.

Is there a module that generate a PDF file with an output that would be sent to a printer?

Comment: If you need css handling I guess your best bet would a local webserver that takes screenshots, there are plenty of similar question on stackoverflow for that issue. but for sake of ease implement any webservice for that, I made some good experience with http://convertapi.com/ additionally you will probably have to make sure the right css is used for that request.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Printer, email and PDF versions](http://drupal.org/project/print) module.

> This module allows you to generate the following printer-friendly
>   versions of any node:
>
> Printer-friendly version (webpage format) (at
>   www.example.com/print/nid)
>
> PDF version (at www.example.com/printpdf/nid)
>
> Send by email (at www.example.com/printmail/nid)
>
> where nid is the node id of content to render.

Comment: It uses its own print.tpl.php template. I would like something that builds a content using my hmtl.tpl.php, page.tpl.php etc.

Comment: @NetExpert, how can you do that? If we use `page.tpl.php` we will get all css/images in print page. If you still want to use `page.tpl.php` consider invoking the `theme` fn provided by that module

Comment: @nikhil-m I use CSS (print media) to hide what I do not want. You can look at Zen template for an example.

The module makes an output inconsistent. You receive a different looking page that one you receive by using a print command of a browser.

Comment: @nikhil-m Using a theme function looks promising. I replaced print.tpl.php content with <?php print theme('html', $variables); ?>. I have got my html now. However a page content is missing. How should I build a render array for a page (I believe I could add it within theme_preprocess_print())?

Comment: @NetExpert, take a look at how they print/render content in `print.tpl.php`

Comment: @nikhil-m They just print a content which is a node only. I need to process a page, a region etc.. The problem with using a html.tpl.php is it prints $page and it is blank now.